# how much data my windows phone mango based application will consume for WCF operation service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, windows-phone-7

my Windows Phone mango based  application will update its location to our main application in head office when ever the position will change and the Position Threshold is set to 20m. The other thing i have put on this update is that I want the update only once in a minute. So application should only hit the head office every 1 minute regardless if the position has changed multiple times during this minute.

I am using Json string to transfer the data to WCF operation and that operation is one way. so including Request and response headers and the Geo Position data which inclides, lat, long and speed, I need help if somebody could help me in estimating the totoal monthly data usage because the data sim is only allowed 500 mb of data.

I am not looking for perfect answer but I was confused and posted my question here. so please forgive me if this looks bit stupid question.

Thanks

Comment: If size is the issue, have you considered something like protobuf, and a raw BLOB response? However: you should be able this yourself; trace it in fiddler etc; estimate a typical request + response size; multiply by response/query rate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is the size of transferred data, you could consider to "zip" them and transferring it as byte[]

if you want to trace the size of transfers, you could sniff data on server or (simpler way to do it) testing the communication with a proxy (fiddler, for example).

Remember also that providers add header data to encapsulate tcp packets and those data are not received from the server